# Power menu lacks restart command

Tags: release-freya, power, suspend

The power menu in the right upper corner lacks restart. If I press physical power button i get a menu containing the restart.

Also the suspend in the right upper corner seems to work differently than when it's selected after pressing the actual power button.

Mbr Patte

Comment: What do you mean by "differently"?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is clear to you, but the lack of a restart option is by design. You can submit a feature request to (if I'm not mistaken) [wingpanel-indicator-session](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-session) asking the developers to reconsider that decision. If you do, please add a comment here linking to it, so others can participate.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is clear to you (both), but in fact there is a restart option which is shown after you click *Shutdown...* in the menu (hence the parenthesis)

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the menu entry called *Shutdown...* it does not turn off the system immediately but instead opens a dialog, where you can also click on *Restart* (pictured in the middle).

Alternatively you can just type "Restart" into Slingshot or use the terminal command `sudo shutdown -r now`.

[image: Options to Restart and Shutdown]

Comment: Out of curiosity, how come your power menu dropdown menu looks so different to mine? Mine has 'about this computer', 'system settings' etc. Nor the big user icons.

Comment: Damn, didn't think of that. I am using a yet-unreleased version of WingPanel from an unstable repository (staging), so the indicators are quite different than what you usually see on Freya.

Comment: A glimpse of the future. ;)

Comment: Hello,  quassy, your comment was right. Another menu with the restart inside is opened after i click Shutdown... So that is solved.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking the little checkmark under the downvote button. This makes it easier for other supporters to see that it's resolved.